# Zend_Form : Adding fields in sub-forms on user's click

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-sub-form

I'm having a zend form - comprised of a number of zend - sub forms,  where the user is creating a new question (its a content management system).
In one of the subforms, the user can click on a button to add more textfields, like this:

[----------]
[----------]
[click to add more]

which should give

[----------]
[----------]
[----------]
[click to add more]

I'm trying to set a flag in the sub form in question - or set a count on how many times the button has been clicked, to add that many total fields to the subform - but its simply not working.
I tried using a static count variable - but the value doesnt get incremented at all.

Any thoughts on how to do this in a Zend-subform within a zend form? 
I'll definitely update if I hit a solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I used Sessions to store the click.
i tried doing this with javascript but within the subform it was not working.
if i simply have such a situation where there is just 1 form (no subforms), the javascript solution works fine.
effectively, just increment the counter by one onclick.
with sessions, or some other global variable, simply do the same - increment the counter, and unset that var when the form is submitted.
so - when u come back to the form, the previous session var value is not retained.